# RegEx: Match everything but X, then X

Tags: c#, regex

Ill try to make it easy for you to understand:

> ```
>    <!--
>    <BASIC_INFO>
>        KOREAN                      =   ¼®À¯
>        ENGLISH                     =   OIL
>        CODE                        =   AA01
>        ACTIVE                      =   FALSE
>        LABEL                       =   0
>    </BASIC_INFO>
>    <OPTION>
>        ANIMATION                   =   ¿©±â¿¡ ¼³¸í
>    </OPTION>
>    <BUY_INFO>
>        BUYABLE                     =   FALSE
>        BUYTYPE                     =   9
>        BUYOPTION                   =   0
>        COST                        =   0
>        ADD_DINAR                   =   0
>        REQ_BP                      =   0
>        REQ_LVL                     =   1
>        RANDOM_NUM                  =   0
>    </BUY_INFO>
>    <USE_INFO>
>        APPLY_TARGET                =   0
>        APPLY_OPTION                =   0
>        ADD_POING                   =   0
>        DURATIONTIME                =   0
>    </USE_INFO>
>    <ABILITY_INFO>
>    </ABILITY_INFO>
>    //-->
>    <!--
>    <BASIC_INFO>
>        KOREAN                      =   Âü³ª¹«
>        ENGLISH                     =   OAK
>        CODE                        =   AB01
>        ACTIVE                      =   FALSE
>        LABEL                       =   0
>    </BASIC_INFO>
>    <OPTION>
>        ANIMATION                   =   ¿©±â¿¡ ¼³¸í
>    </OPTION>
>    <BUY_INFO>
>        BUYABLE                     =   FALSE
>        BUYTYPE                     =   9
>        BUYOPTION                   =   0
>        COST                        =   0
>        ADD_DINAR                   =   0
>        REQ_BP                      =   0
>        REQ_LVL                     =   1
>        RANDOM_NUM                  =   0
>    </BUY_INFO>
>    <USE_INFO>
>        APPLY_TARGET                =   0
>        APPLY_OPTION                =   0
>        ADD_POING                   =   0
>        DURATIONTIME                =   0
>    </USE_INFO>
>    <ABILITY_INFO>
>    </ABILITY_INFO>
>    //-->
> ```

I wanted to match everything within <!-- //-->, can't find a regular expression for it...
The first match should look something like this:

> ```
>    <BASIC_INFO>
>        KOREAN                      =   ¼®À¯
>        ENGLISH                     =   OIL
>        CODE                        =   AA01
>        ACTIVE                      =   FALSE
>        LABEL                       =   0
>    </BASIC_INFO>
>    <OPTION>
>        ANIMATION                   =   ¿©±â¿¡ ¼³¸í
>    </OPTION>
>    <BUY_INFO>
>        BUYABLE                     =   FALSE
>        BUYTYPE                     =   9
>        BUYOPTION                   =   0
>        COST                        =   0
>        ADD_DINAR                   =   0
>        REQ_BP                      =   0
>        REQ_LVL                     =   1
>        RANDOM_NUM                  =   0
>    </BUY_INFO>
>    <USE_INFO>
>        APPLY_TARGET                =   0
>        APPLY_OPTION                =   0
>        ADD_POING                   =   0
>        DURATIONTIME                =   0
>    </USE_INFO>
>    <ABILITY_INFO>
>    </ABILITY_INFO>
> ```

```
<!--(?<NodeContent>[^//\-\-\>]*)//-->
```

This is what I have tried, but it matches each character! This means if /, - and > is inside <!-- //-->, it fails. Does someone know how to solve this?

## edit

This is how the whole document structure looks like: http://pastebin.com/cyESrLTB - My goal is to convert it to XML.

Comment: Use a XML parser.

Comment: `[^ABC]` means "not `A`, `B` or `C`", not "not `ABC`".

Comment: Based on a comment on one of the answers, is your regex purely to extract the XML from a much larger (non-XML) document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<!--(?<NodeContent>.*?)//-->
```

The `?` marks the matching as 'lazy', so it will attempt to match as few characters as possible. Breaking this down:

- `<!--` - Match `<!--`
- `(?<NodeContent>.*?)` - Match `.*?` lazily, and give it a group name of `NodeContent`.
- `//-->` - Match `//-->`

Comment: `/` doesn't need to be escaped as far as I know.

Comment: @Dukeling It appears to be optional. I'll remove it for readability, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Regex here, Use an html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(fname);
var comments = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()")
                .Select(n => n.InnerText)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Using an XML parser as It'sNotALie suggested in his comment seems like a better idea. The text isn't HTML.

Comment: Well its kinda tricky.. That was only a part of a big document.
http://pastebin.com/cyESrLTB

Comment: @Dan It is xml or html, not importand. HAP can parse it. BTW: I tested the code before posting and it works..

Comment: Sorry, wasn't familiar with HAP. Made the assumption based on its name that it was strictly an HTML parser. Your answer should say "Use an XPATH parser like the one offered in HtmlAgilityPack".